# Smarter Column Reference in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to organise my data the following way:

```
comptime <- expdata$EXP1TCD5 + expdata$EXP1TCD12 + ... + expdata$EXP1TCD68
```

What's happening here is I want to get every 7th column of the data set starting from a certain point of the data.frame. Can anyone advise a smarter way to reference the columns, because I need to compile around 60 mini data.frames like this.

If possible of course.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about programming in R and it lacks reproducible example.

Comment: @Tim please don't!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you want to do something like this:

```
rowSums( expdata[ , seq(5,68,by = 7) ] )
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but in `expdata$EXP1TCD5` the `EXP1TCD5` references a column. So I guess I need `colSums` or some such? Or not? Anyway thanks! That is exactly what I was looking for

Comment: That depends on your objective:) The code you posted will generate the row sums through vectorized addition. If that was not your intention, you can use colSums of course.

Comment: Just tried it on my data.frame. Works like a charm! Thanks!!